# WAMP installation Apache not parsing PHP code despite it being configured in httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, wamp

I downloaded and installed WampServer 2.5 64 bits. Installation worked fine and my WAMP server status is green. I can connect to localhost and see the admin panel. I can log into the mysql console and it seems to work fine as well.

The big problem is that the server seems to not be parsing PHP code at all. When I click on phpinfo() from the localhost panel I only see the source code. Here are a few lines of what I see when I click on the phpinfo() link. The url it takes me to is

```
http://localhost/?phpinfo

rder="0" cellpadding="3" width="600">
<tr><td class="e">LDAP Support </td><td class="v">enabled </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">RCS Version </td><td class="v">$Id$ </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Total Links </td><td class="v">0/unlimited </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">API Version </td><td class="v">3001 </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Vendor Name </td><td class="v">OpenLDAP </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">Vendor Version </td><td class="v">20433 </td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">SASL Support </td><td class="v">Enabled </td></tr>
</table><br />
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" width="600">
<tr class="h"><th>Directive</th><th>Local Value</th><th>Master Value</th></tr>
<tr><td class="e">ldap.max_links</td><td class="v">Unlimited</td><td             vclass="v">Unlimited</td></tr>
</table><br />
```

I've dug around and most places say to make sure that apache is properly configured but I've checked my httpd.conf file and I have the following lines in there.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3
```

Along with the

```
LoadModule php5_module
```

which has the appropriate file path following it.

I've tried re-installing wamp several times over several versions and in different directories. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

A few images that might be able to help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vBtt.png
Wamp Server Icon is green.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI8Tx.png
Localhost URL WAMP panel.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mldhs.png
What happens when I try to navigate to the phpInfo() link on the WAMP panel.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWDiF.png
What happens when I try to navigate to the phpmyadmin link on the WAMP panel.

Comment: What is the extension of the file?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I've checked the \wamp\www\index.php that I'm assuming is providing the localhost page and I've found this snippet of code.

  <ul class="tools">
  <li><a href="?phpinfo=1">phpinfo()</a></li>
  <li><a href="phpmyadmin/">phpmyadmin</a></li>
 </ul>

I think that's where the links are populated. Unfortunately I have very little experience with WAMP.

I should also mention 2 things.

1. I am running Windows 7.
2. PHPMyadmin linked from the wamp localhost page behaves the same.

Comment: Oh, can you completely uninstall WAMP Server and reinstall it? Did you install VC Redist?

Comment: I can do that. I don't believe I have but I can check to make sure, does it show up under the Programs and Features tab in Control Panel?

Comment: Check it out and let me know! :)

Comment: I've just checked and I have several entries for Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable under my program list in control panel. The entries vary in years, including 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012. Some have version numbers and some have x86 and x64 denominations.

Comment: Just leave it as such. You have correctly installed it. Can you check to see if the W icon is green in colour?

Comment: It is green and I've also logged in to mysql through the console just to make sure it's running. No problems there.

Comment: Crazy... Seriously! `:O`

Comment: Try the 32bit installation..

Comment: It is really strange. I've added some screenshots in the original post to show what I'm seeing.

Comment: DarkBee I've tried the 32bit installation and it behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing the standard WAMPServer home page when you click the wampmanager link

```
wampmanager -> localhost
```

And you see this web page, or something similiar

[image: Homepage]

Then PHP is working, because this page is written in PHP

Are you using Explorer and double clicking on the page you are trying to run?

If so DONT, use the browser address bar like you would for any web page. You have to go via Apache so that the PHP interpreter gets involved in the processing.

Also make sure that the script file you are trying to run has the `.php' extension or Apache wont pass the script to PHP anyway.

**ADDITIONAL Chrome Issue suggestion**

Ah right. Chrome is becoming a real pain to developers lately.

Try this:-

- Click the triple bar icon ( Customise and control Chrome settings ), top right of Chrome browser.
- Click advanced settings
- Under the Network section press the `Change proxy settings`
- That should launch a `Internet Properties` standard windows dialog.
- Click the `Lan Settings` button at the bottom of the dialog
- That should open a `Local Area Network (LAN) settings` dialog
- Make sure that 'Use a proxy Server for your lan` checkbox is unchecked.

If its not this it is something very similiar that Chrome is assuming by default that is interfering with normal operations.

Comment: You're right, PHP is running, but I'm using Chrome and when I click on phpinfo() on the wamp server localhost panel, one very similar to the image you've posted, I see the source code of what I'm assuming to be the file linked to on that page. I've edited the original post with some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I messed up. I was running a firewall, ZoneAlarm to be specific, and it seems that when certain php functions were called the firewall would block them and mess up the server. I'm sorry I can't present a more technical answer but I'm trying to learn more so I will be able to in the future.